# Javascript function does not fire when I add a parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, parameters

This function works:

```
function setIframeSrc()
{
    var iframeSrc = "folder=999d146783e5452680943c9097453026&amp;img=http%3A%2F%2Fuat%2Dishare%2Eihtech%2Ecom%2FStyle%20Library%2FMedia%20Player%2FVideoPreview%2Epng&amp;title=1&amp;lHome=1&amp;lOwner=1";
    var iframeBase = document.getElementById("videoFrame").src;
    document.getElementById("videoFrame").src = iframeBase + iframeSrc;
}
```

and is called by this in another function:

```
  $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() 
                         {
                              var ID = $(this).attr("ows_ID");
                              var Title = $(this).attr("ows_Title");
                              var URL = $(this).attr("ows_URL");
                              //var empName = $(this).attr("ows_EmpName");
                              //var jobtitle =  $(this).attr("ows_JobTitle");
                              //var dept =  $(this).attr("ows_Department"); 
                                alert(URL);
                              $("#myHTMLTable").append("<tr align='middle'>" +
                               "<td align='left'>"+ID+"</td>" +
                               "<td align='left'>"+Title+"</td>" +
                               "<td  align='left'><a id='uri' href='#' onclick='return setIframeSrc()' >Link To Movie</a></td>" +
                               "</tr>");



                           });
```

When I try to add a parameter:

```
function setIframeSrc(URL)
{
    var iframeSrc = "folder=999d146783e5452680943c9097453026&amp;img=http%3A%2F%2Fuat%2Dishare%2Eihtech%2Ecom%2FStyle%20Library%2FMedia%20Player%2FVideoPreview%2Epng&amp;title=1&amp;lHome=1&amp;lOwner=1";
    var iframeBase = document.getElementById("videoFrame").src;
    document.getElementById("videoFrame").src = iframeBase + iframeSrc;
}
```

and call it from getMyListData()

```
 $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() 
                         {
                              var ID = $(this).attr("ows_ID");
                              var Title = $(this).attr("ows_Title");
                              var URL = $(this).attr("ows_URL");
                              //var empName = $(this).attr("ows_EmpName");
                              //var jobtitle =  $(this).attr("ows_JobTitle");
                              //var dept =  $(this).attr("ows_Department"); 
                                alert(URL);
                              $("#myHTMLTable").append("<tr align='middle'>" +
                               "<td align='left'>"+ID+"</td>" +
                               "<td align='left'>"+Title+"</td>" +
                               "<td  align='left'><a id='uri' href='#' onclick='return setIframeSrc(URL)' >Link To Movie</a></td>" +
                               "</tr>");



                           });
```

The function fails to execute.  Can I assign a parameter in the dynamic javascript?  What am I doing wrong here

Comment: [Check your console for errors.](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/185/hello-world/714/using-console-log#t=201610201854491028563) You're attempting to pass a global variable, `URL`, for every element. Using inline event handlers tends to be a hassle. I'd suggest using [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead.

Comment: console does not show me any errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
onclick='return setIframeSrc(" + URL + ")'
```

Comment: May need to be `onclick='return setIframeSrc(\"" + URL + "\")' ` so that the URL ends up in quotes.

Comment: @VinnyGuitara A few things, 1.  first line in setIframeSrc, log or alert the value of URL.  2.  view source on the page after it loads, and look carefully at how that HTML is getting stuffed into the page.  Make sure all the quotes make sense, etc.  maybe paste the page source back into this post.